# Scala Eclipse IDE configuration

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, ide

Already installed java, scala and SBT followed steps of instructions on `Lynda`

seems work in terminal

```
v1020-wn-206-156:~ zhongyuan$ scala
Welcome to Scala 2.12.1 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_121).
Type in expressions for evaluation. Or try :help.

scala>
```

Now I want to install Eclipse Scala IDE.Just did the following steps:

1. Down load Eclipse IDE, unzip it and then drag it to `Application`.
2. create an project

[hello world](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9ZpKX.png)

[config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxUCG.png)

Is there any way to add any compiler link to the IDE
(like what I did for C++ IDE and Python?)

Did I miss any steps or did anything incorrect.

How to set up the configurations?

Comment: Are you asking how to add Scala compiler to Eclipse IDE?

Comment: Yes? I have never used this IDE before...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add another version just go in the Eclipse Preferences and add the path into Scala -> Installations

[image: Scala -> Installations]

Then go to the Project Preferences and change the version of Scala your need.

[image]

Comment: I just installed scala 2.12.1 by using `brew install scala` and I can't find the directory for those `.jar` files.